# Pronunciation of кафе

Tags: произношение

Why the consonant "ф" in "кафе" is not soft (= palatalized), given that it is before the soft vowel "e"? Do loanwords usually break pronunciation rules?

Comment: You are correct. I was wrong - when I think about it, "январе" and "начале", "доколе" "праве",etc. also have a soft 'e', but 'Боже' and "ближе" and "дальше" have a hard one. So it's the preceding sound determines whether it's soft or hard in non-loan words. I will delete my answer as it's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why the consonant "ф" in "кафе" is not soft (= palatalized), given that it is before the soft vowel "e"?

Most likely because that is closer to the original French pronunciation.

> Do loanwords usually break pronunciation rules?

My impression is they at least tend to break the rules *more often*.

By the way, Russian also seems to be better about preserving the original pronunciation of foreign names--the stress in particular--compared to English.

Comment: Russian is similar to German in that regard of trying to preserve the original pronunciation. English, French, Spanish and Italian *usually* pronounce loanwords as they would pronounce it if it was a native word.